# Jest test fails with Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a Node project using Typescript and Jest. Currently I have this project structure

[image]

With this `tsconfig.json` file

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
```

this `jest.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

and this `package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/App.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/App.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.4",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2"
  }
}
```

I created a test file in my tests directory

```
import { App } from '../src/App';

describe('Generating App', () => {
  let app: App;

  test('It runs a test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

but unfortunately I get a syntax error

> SyntaxError: C:...\tests\App.test.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";"
>   (5:9)

at my `app` variable. It seems the test runner is not able to understand Typescript code. How can I fix my configuration to support Typescript in test files for Jest?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try to add typescript extension in jest config :

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.ts?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'json', 'node'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
};
```

And then load the jest config in your package.json test script :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: thanks for your help. When I run `npm run test` I the pattern returns 0 matches with `Run with '--passWithNoTests' to exit with code 0
In C:\...
  6 files checked`, it seems it is not able to use the `tests` directory .. =?

Comment: I think it's because you have your tests outside src folder so I have updated the jest config by adding `roots: ['<rootDir>'],` instead of `roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],` it should work now :)

Comment: Your tests are located in the `tests` folder, but in `jest.config.js` you have prescribed folder `__tests__`. Different paths are specified, and there are no matches for this.

Comment: in my case it doesn't transpile ts files into js. when I added transform property of answer, it started to transpile and passed to another problem which was solved by tsConfig property. Thanks!

Comment: `npm install ts-node -D` and adding the `transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest' }` to the jest config solved my issue, thanks @Putxe

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was failing because I did not set properly the typescript support for Jest. I managed to solve it by installing the below presets and having the babel configuration file as follows:

**babel.config.json**

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue in regards to a basic babel setup for node jest tests. However, if someone is using this solution, remove `["@babel/preset-react", { "runtime": "automatic" }]` if you don't have react!

Answer (score 0):

tsconfig.json

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "jsx": "react-jsx"
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was actually the solution for me, so thanks.