# Google Cloud Function: jest test does not recognize typescript syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-platform, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I have a sample nodejs project which is a Google Pubsub Cloud Functions sample where I am trying out Jest as the testing tool.

When I am running npm script to do the unit test I get an error that indicates that typescript is not being recognized.

I am doing just **npm run test:unit** that I have included into my package.json file but I am getting following error.

```
> jest ./test/unit

 FAIL  test/unit/orders.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: C:\Development\GCP-Jest\src\index.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";" (1:10)

    > 1 | let pgPool: any;
        |           ^
      2 | 
      3 | export const orders = async (event: any): Promise<void> => {
      4 |   let msgDataStr: string;

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6387:17)
      at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7704:16)
      at Parser.semicolon (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7686:40)
      at Parser.parseVarStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10371:10)
      at Parser.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9967:21)
      at Parser.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9900:17)
      at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10476:25)
      at Parser.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10463:10)
      at Parser.parseTopLevel (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9829:10)
      at Parser.parse (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11341:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.795s
Ran all test suites matching /.\\test\\unit/i.
```

Project structure looks like following.

[image: Project Structure]

**src/index.js**

```
let pgPool: any;

export const orders = async (event: any): Promise<void> => {
  let msgDataStr: string;
  msgDataStr = event.data;
  pgPool = 1;
  console.error("Error in Unmarshalling data from event" + msgDataStr + pgPool);
};
```

**test/unit/order.test.js**

```
const orders = require('../../src');

describe('DataInflow Orders', () => {
    let consoleSpy;
    beforeEach(function() {
        consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'error').mockImplementation();
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        consoleSpy.mockRestore();
    });

    it('print outs the error message when received JSON is blank', async () => {
        const message = '';
        const event = {
            data: {
                data: Buffer.from(message).toString('base64'),
            },
            attributes: {},
        };

        await orders.orders(event);
        expect(consoleSpy.mock.calls[1][0]).toEqual(expect.stringContaining('Error in Unmarshalling data from event'));
    });
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2018",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./src/@types",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "src/@types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "lib"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "poc-cf",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Cloud Functions",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.30.3",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "pg": "^7.12.0"
    },
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "types": "lib/@types",
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "setupFiles": [
            "dotenv/config"
        ],
        "roots": [
            "<rootDir>/test"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint src/*/**",
        "build": "tsc",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:unit": "jest ./test/unit",
        "test:int": "jest ./test/integration",
        "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.2.1",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
        "@types/pg": "^7.4.14",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
        "child_process": "^1.0.2",
        "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
        "eslint": "^6.2.1",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "typescript": "^3.4.5"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.15.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `ts-jest`, because jest does not compile you typescript code

Comment: I think this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921019/jest-test-fails-with-unexpected-token-expected/57921270?noredirect=1#comment102260645_57921270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ts-jest`, after you installed it.

add `preset` configuration like below to your `jest` configuration.

```js
"jest": {
  "preset": "ts-jest",
}
```

take a look at the tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest#getting-started

Comment: thanks... m not sure but it was working few days back and 2day it stopped working. and I was not having this settings earlier as well...

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already has noted, you need `ts-jest`. Install it as a development dependency.

Another important configuration piece is [`testEnvironment`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string). The default setting for it is `jsdom` and it looks like you may need to set it to `node`.

I'd suggest to have `jest.config.js`. This is a working sample:

```js
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.ts$',
  moduleFileExtensions: [...defaults.moduleFileExtensions, 'ts'],
  roots: [ "<rootDir>/src" ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks... In ur jest.config.js u have mentioned roots as <rootDir>/src. What does it indicates? Folder where tests are or folder where src is? As in my case my test folder is outside of src folder...

Comment: @NikhilGupta The [`roots`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#roots-array-string) setting tells Jest where to look for _both_ test and source files. In my case the `tests` subdirectory was under `src`. Since in your environment that is not the case, you can specify both directories because `roots` is an array. The `roots` link provides an example of that.