# Error while trying to render a react component for tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-test-renderer

I am trying to use `create` from `react-test-renderer` to render a component. That's what I'm trying to do

```
import { ReactTestRenderer, create} from 'react-test-renderer';
let component: ReactTestRenderer;
const createComponent = (tradingBalances: IBalance[]) => {
  component = create(<StakingContainer tradingBalances={tradingBalances} vaultBalances={mockVaultBalances} prices={mockPrices} />);
};
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: .../path/... Unexpected token, expected "," (31:41)

  29 |   let instance: ReactTestInstance;
  30 |   const createComponent = (tradingBalances: IBalance[]) => {
> 31 |     component = create(<StakingContainer tradingBalances={tradingBalances} vaultBalances={mockVaultBalances} prices={mockPrices} />);
     |                                          ^
  32 |   };
```

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Probably not configured jest correctly for typescript. Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921019/jest-test-fails-with-unexpected-token-expected

Comment: @Mellet the thing is, this config works for other tests. I copied the related code from another test. That's the issue.

Comment: Is it a .tsx file?

Comment: Yup, that was it. The test was a ts file. Thanks @pmoleri, You can add an answer with an explanation and I'll select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript compiler is not recognizing React syntax (JSX).
Make sure that your filename uses `.tsx` extension.