# jest: Test suite failed to run, Jest encountered an unexpected token - typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test in react with typescript and I'm experiencing a strange issue. my test will not run and it's returning this error below. I'm trying to write mock test test for my api, I'm attempting to mock axios but I keep getting this error: I have already written a successful snapshot test for another component but this components test isn't working. any assistance would be appreciated thanks.

Here is my error:

```
FAIL src/app/__tests__/Products.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/user/Desktop/work/test/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       8 | import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
       9 |
    > 10 | import axios from 'axios';
         | ^
      11 |
      12 | import { data } from '../temp/data';
      13 | import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/__tests__/Products.test.tsx:10:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

my test that is failing:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';

import Products from '../components/Products';
import { cleanup, render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios';

import { data } from '../temp/data';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

jest.mock('axios');

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;


it('should show something', () => {
  mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Joe Doe',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane Doe',
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { sortBy, sortSelectOptions } from '../utils/utils';
import { Products } from '../types/types';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import { fetchData } from '../endpoints/fetchData';
import { NoResults } from './NoResults';
import PlaceholderImage from '../../assets/placeholder.png';

import Select from './Select';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import '../index.css';

function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState<Products[]>([]);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Products[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [contentTypeValue, setContentTypeValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');

  const productsPerPage = 20;
  const lastIndex = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - productsPerPage;
  const filteredProducts = sortBy?.[filterValue]?.(products) ?? products;
  const currentProducts = filteredProducts.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
  const pages = Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length / productsPerPage);
  const numbers = [...Array(pages + 1).keys()].slice(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setProducts);
    fetchData(setArray);
    setSearchValue('');
  }, []);

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== lastIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== firstIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    }
  };

  const movePages = (id: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(id);
  };

  //Generate content type list
  //Done it this this way as opposed to pulling out every category manually
  const transformContentTypeintoList = [
    ...new Set(products.map((prod) => prod.contentType).flat()),
  ];

  const contentTypeList = transformContentTypeintoList
    .map((item) => {
      return [
        {
          label: item,
          value: item,
        },
      ];
    })
    .flat();

  const handleSort = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFilterValue(event?.target.value);
    //goto page 1 after sort
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleTitleSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSearchValue(value);
    if (value) {
      const filteredData = array.filter((desc: Products) => {
        return desc.title.includes(searchValue);
      });

      setProducts(filteredData);
    } else {
      setProducts(array);
    }
  };

  const handleContentSort = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setContentTypeValue(value);

    if (value) {
      const filtered = array.filter((content: Products) =>
        content.contentType.includes(value),
      );
      setProducts(filtered);
      setCurrentPage(1);
    }
  };

  console.log(array);

  const resetFilter = () => {
    setProducts(array);
    setSearchValue('');
  };

  const mapContentTypes = () => {
    return (
      <Select
        options={contentTypeList}
        datatestid={'contentTypeId'}
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) =>
          handleContentSort(e)
        }
        defaultOption={'Select Content Type'}
        label={'Filter by Content type '}
      />
    );
  };

  const mapProducts = () => {
    if (currentProducts.length === 0 && searchValue.length > 0) {
      return <NoResults reset={resetFilter} />;
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="searchContainer">
            <TextInput
              className="searchInput"
              placeholder="search by title"
              value={searchValue}
              datatestid={'searchId'}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                handleTitleSearch(e)
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="filterContainer">
              <div>
                <Pagination
                  numbers={numbers}
                  currentPage={currentPage}
                  prevPage={prevPage}
                  movePages={movePages}
                  nextPage={nextPage}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="filter">
                {mapContentTypes()}
                <Select
                  options={sortSelectOptions}
                  datatestid={'sortTestId'}
                  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) =>
                    handleSort(e)
                  }
                  defaultOption={'Sort by'}
                  label={'Sort by '}
                />
                <button onClick={resetFilter}>Reset filter</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {currentProducts.map((product: Products) => {
              return (
                <div className="item" key={product.id}>
                  <LazyLoadImage
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    placeholderSrc={PlaceholderImage}
                    src={product.imgSet.sm.src}
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <div
                    aria-label={`Product${product.id}`}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    className="innerContainer">
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Name`}>
                      Name: {product.title}
                    </span>
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Price`}>
                      Price: {product.price}
                    </span>
                    <span
                      className="text"
                      tabIndex={0}
                      aria-label={` Stock level`}>
                      Stock level: {product.productType}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <Pagination
              numbers={numbers}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              prevPage={prevPage}
              movePages={movePages}
              nextPage={nextPage}
            />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="container">{mapProducts()}</div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my fetch function:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchData = async (setter: (arg0: any) => any) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3030/products');
    setter(res?.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest test fails with Unexpected token, expected ";"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921019/jest-test-fails-with-unexpected-token-expected)

Comment: Not really unfortunately, still experiencing the same issues